# Unintended exception: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative - 5.7.12

Tags: mysql

I have a table (`offers_lowest`) with ~120m rows, so I created a view containing data from the last 7 full days to improve performance, but whenever I try to select the view, or `offers_lowest` itself (in MySQL workbench) I get the following exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

This didn't happen until I created the view, seems weird that it affects the original table as well as the view.

Here's the create table statement for `offers_lowest`:

```
CREATE TABLE `offers_lowest` (
  `cap_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lowest_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deposit` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `term` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mileage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finance_type` enum('P','B') DEFAULT NULL,
  `offer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `broker_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_lowest_price` (`lowest_price`),
  KEY `idx_specials_extra` (`finance_type`,`date`),
  KEY `idx_specials_id_price` (`offer_id`,`lowest_price`),
  KEY `idx_price_history` (`cap_id`,`deposit`,`term`,`mileage`,`finance_type`,`date`,`offer_id`,`broker_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And here's the create statement for the view:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `moneyshake`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `offers_lowest_7d` AS
    SELECT 
        `offers_lowest`.`cap_id` AS `cap_id`,
        `offers_lowest`.`date` AS `date`,
        `offers_lowest`.`lowest_price` AS `lowest_price`,
        `offers_lowest`.`deposit` AS `deposit`,
        `offers_lowest`.`term` AS `term`,
        `offers_lowest`.`mileage` AS `mileage`,
        `offers_lowest`.`finance_type` AS `finance_type`,
        `offers_lowest`.`offer_id` AS `offer_id`,
        `offers_lowest`.`broker_id` AS `broker_id`
    FROM
        `offers_lowest`
    WHERE
        ((`offers_lowest`.`date` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 8 DAY))
            AND (`offers_lowest`.`date` < CAST(NOW() AS DATE))
            AND (`offers_lowest`.`finance_type` = 'P'))
```

The view cuts the row number down to ~5m.

The explain statement for the `SELECT * FROM the_view`:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | offers_lowest |  | range | idx_specials_extra, idx_offers_lowest_date | idx_specials_extra | 6 |  | 10349736 | 100.00 | Using index condition |

I've looked up the issue and it seems it's a bug, but is there any way I can get around it?

Comment: The table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Since `VIEWs` don't provide any performance benefit, you may as well avoid it.

Comment: Use `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of casting `NOW()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Rick James, changed the CAST function to CURDATE() and it fixed it.